# android: is it possible to know runner's speed by GPS?

Tags: android, android-activity

i'm developing a runner / walker app for android that records runner's activity: distance and time.
when the user click on start button, the app starts to record. when the user clicks on stop button, the app stops to record and calculate distance and time between the two points.

**does the phone's gps can detect minor speeds like 1 - 10 kph? is it possible?**

function getSpeed(); doesn't work for this purpose - I have tried with my phone.
I was thinking about calculating speed by distance and time formula. but the distance is inaccurate, so I suppose it won't work... should I give it a try? maybe someone here has experience with this issue?

thanks for help

Comment: You may try using pedometer: https://code.google.com/p/pedometer/

Comment: When you say getSpeed() didn't work, what do you mean? And what kind of accuracy are you really looking for? Distance/time should still work if you're willing to sacrifice a little accuracy.

Comment: getspeed returns 0 in slow speeds

Comment: speed is, by definition, distance / time. distance can only be approximated by measuring a number of point and filtering out eccentric values, then summing the distance between these points, which is a discrete approximation. Your GPS does not have more information than you have, nor can it magically come up with some more values. Therefore, If you consider that measuring a distance this way is inaccurate, tough luck.